# Why doesn't pip freeze show opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, pip, package-managers

I've installed OpenCV on my mac and I can import it in Python:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.2.0'
```

but when I use `pip freeze` the package is not in the list:

```
$ pip freeze | grep cv
```

How can this be?

Comment: Because you may have installed it without pip

Comment: @ZdaR - Of course. How stupid of me. If you add your comment as an answer I can accept it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @ZdaR suggested in the comment above, it was because OpenCV wasn't installed through pip.

Comment: Can we check, how that package has been installed?

Comment: if it is not pip then it can be through apt or from source. apt doesn't install the latest version however source has the latest version. May be this can help to figure out the source of installation.