# pip freeze not showing package

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, ubuntu, pip

For some reason I can't see opencv printing via pip freeze, however I can import it.

```
pip freeze | grep opencv
pip3 freeze | grep opencv

python -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__file__)"
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
python -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)"
3.4.2

python3 -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__file__)"
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
python3 -c "import cv2; print(cv2.__version__)"
3.4.2

python -V
Python 3.6.8

python3 -V
Python 3.6.8

pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)

pip3 -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)
```

I have alias for python3 in bashrc:

```
cat ~/.bashrc | tail
alias python=python3
alias pip=pip3
```

Ubuntu version:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Comment: Does `pip -V` and `pip3 -V` give same answer?

Comment: Does `pip freeze` output correctly? Try upgrading pip: `pip install --upgrade pip` and try again?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42313103/why-doesnt-pip-freeze-show-opencv

Answer (score 1):

When you freeze the packages by pip, it will show the packages installed by pip and opencv may not be installed through pip.

Comment: Is it possible to determine how package was installed?

Comment: If you cannot see the packages from `pip list` then the packages are installed manually but don't know how.